# Can you say Hadran without meat

Tags: talmud-gemara, meat, eating, siyum

I have a few questions about meat and Hadran (Hadran for finishing a tractate of Talmud)

1. Can you make a Siyum without meat?
2. If yes then can you say Hadran without meat?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29853/759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to eat meat to have a siyum. To just wash for bread or just to even have cake with soda is good enough. See Horav Chaim Kanievesky Shlita quoted in Yoma Tova L’rabanan page 107:4, refer to Orchos
Rabbeinu 2:page 57:6.

The Reason why we can eat during the nine days is because we are making a seudas mitzvah, but then again you do not need to. Rama 551:10
And Elya Rabbah 26, Chai Adom 133:16, Aruch Ha’shulchan 28, Eretz Tzvi 1:79,

Comment: The chabad custom allows it since you are taking place in a seudas mitzvah

Comment: It seems I had some typos in my previous comment. I meant to write that I have seen people say hadran during the nine days without any food. I actually haven't ever been at a siyum outside chabad. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How does it count as a proper "seudah" without meat and cooked food?

Comment: @SAH when I have gone to siyumim on Erev Pesach so first borns need not fast, there is not typically meat or hot food served.  Similarly, at the 13th Siyum HaShas of Daf Yomi in MetLife Stadium, meat was not provided to all attendees, though it was available to those in very pricey seats.